# Update shiny UI only when tab is selected

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny dashboard with multiple tabs. In one of the tabs, a slow database query fills the choices for a dropdown menu. I want the slow database query to execute only when the relevant tab is selected.

In the following ReprEx, the `slowDatabaseQuery` is executed at launch and blocks the R process.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      "panel1", 
      "Panel 1 content"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "panel2", 
      "Panel 2 content",
      selectizeInput(
        "selected", 
        label = "Selector", 
        choices = NULL
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  slowDatabaseQuery <- reactive({
    Sys.sleep(5)
    return(c("C", "D"))
  })
  
  observe(
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session, 
      "selected", 
      choices = slowDatabaseQuery(), 
      selected = "C", 
      server = TRUE
    )    
  )
  
  output$text <- renderText(input$selected)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

A partial solution would be using `renderUI()` instead of `updateSelectizeInput()`. However, I would like to use the `server = TRUE` argument which is only available in `updateSelectizeInput()` and do not like that it would take the UI element a long time to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can provide your `tabsetPanel` with an `id` and observe the selections via `observeEvent`.

There are two different options in the code below.

1. The DB query is done each time `tab2` is selected.
2. The DB query is done the first time `tab2` is selected in the current shiny-session (commented out).

---

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabsetPanelID",
    tabPanel(
      "panel1", 
      "Panel 1 content"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "panel2", 
      "Panel 2 content",
      selectizeInput(
        "selected", 
        label = "Selector", 
        choices = NULL
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  slowDatabaseQuery <- reactive({
    Sys.sleep(5)
    return(c("C", "D"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$tabsetPanelID,{
    if(input$tabsetPanelID == "panel2"){
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session,
        "selected",
        choices = slowDatabaseQuery(),
        selected = "C",
        server = TRUE
      )
    }
  })
  
  # observeEvent(input$tabsetPanelID == "panel2", {
  #     updateSelectizeInput(
  #       session,
  #       "selected",
  #       choices = slowDatabaseQuery(),
  #       selected = "C",
  #       server = TRUE
  #     )
  # }, once = TRUE) # should the query be done only once or each time the tab is selected?
  
  output$text <- renderText(input$selected)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```